# Odd JavaScript getElementsByName undefined error

Tags: javascript, undefined

Okay, I've seriously got to be missing something or I'm crazy. Here's the code I'm having an issue with, it is inside an onchange event:

```
console.log( (this.parentNode.parentNode) );
// fine prints the elements

console.log( (this.parentNode.parentNode).getElementsByName('otherposition[]') );
// gives me undefined error

(this.parentNode.parentNode).getElementsByName('otherposition[]')[0].style.opacity = '1';
// same error.
```

Comment: We need to know the context. Without a context, `this` refers to the window, which has no `parentNode`.

Comment: there's no difference between the 1st and 2nd line. But the second gives error. That's odd. Are u sure everythings's correct?

Comment: Your first two lines appear to be identical. You're saying one prints correctly, and the other gives an error, and there's nothing in between those lines?

Comment: i think you have to check your 2nd line because if it is creating the problem then why 1st one is not ,because they are the same

Comment: @Kolink thanks guys, fixed the two lines they were not supposed to be identical. Also added the context. This is in an onchange event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByName` is a method of `document`, elements doesn't have such method.